# Реализация своего собственного Task'a для Ant в java

Tags: java, ant

Я хочу написать свой собственный Task для ant. Вроде  бы нашел на [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop) Как пишутся свои Task'и. Но там предлагается использовать typedef для подключения реализованных библиотек, а мне нужно каким-то образом сделать так, что-бы не нужно было каждый раз подключать lib через taskdef. То есть, чтобы мой Task работал в любом buildfile без явного указания,что его необходимо подключить. Как такое можно сделать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Зачем Вы используете ант, да ок проверенное решение. Есть ведь мавен/градл

Comment: @GenCloud Мы проходим именно Ant, поэтому сижу и разбираюсь с ним. Но судя по огромному количеству отзывов о Maven, многие действительно считают его лучше.

Comment: не могу ничего посоветовать в данный момент, смотрите доки/семплы

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрев внимательно, я обнаружил, что пропустил важную строчку, в которой и кроется ответ на мой вопрос. Необходимо добавить имя Task'а и имя класса который его реализует в default.properties который находится в пакете org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs. После этого можно будет использовать как встроенную задачу.